# How to insert data for one to many relationship between two tables in WPF c# using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, desktop-application

```
try
{
    foreach (IEnumerable<string> row in itemgridshow.Items)
    {
        var valueslist = row.ToList();

        Order_Item oi = new Order_Item();
        oi.Item_Description = valueslist[0].ToString();
        oi.Item_Copy = int.Parse(valueslist[1].ToString());
        oi.Item_Price = int.Parse(valueslist[2].ToString());
        oi.Item_Amount = int.Parse(valueslist[3].ToString());
        oi.Item_Image = valueslist[4].ToString();

        neworder.Order_Item.Add(oi);

        db.Order_Item.Add(oi);
    }

    db.Order_Master.Add(neworder);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

`Order_Master` is the primary table and `Order_Item` is the secondary table. I want to insert `Order_Master` record & many `Order_item` details in a single save button operation.

`db` is the context name.

For `order_item` data is pass through datagrid (itemgrid.items) in string array.

All looks good and above code doesn't cause any errors, but data is not inserted into the database. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Where is `neworder` declared, it at least can't be seen in this code excerpt. Also I'm not certain how smart EF is if you try to add an `order_item` to `neworder` before the latter exists in the database.

Comment: neworder is declared outside try block. sorry i forgot to mention.

Comment: We need to see how neworder is being declared. Also, how is neworder.Order_Item being instantiated? You're calling Add on it inside of your loop, but we never see it initialized. Also, how are your entities configured. Your code is syntactically correct and has a few extra calls you don't need, so if it's not saving, it's likely something wrong with the entities.

Comment: so, do you get any Exceptions in the catch part of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any logic issues with the code snippet above.

Try restructuring the code, encapsulating the context usage might uncover why the save isn't happening.

```
    public void SaveOrder(IEnumerable<string> rows)
    {
        // Create a new order and add items
        var neworder = new Order_Master();
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            var valueslist = row.ToList();
            var oi = new Order_Item();

            oi.Item_Description = valueslist[0].ToString();
            // Set more properties...

            // Add the item to the order
            neworder.Order_Item.Add(oi);
        }

        // Instance a context, add the order and save
        try
        {
            using (var db = new OrderContext())
            {
                db.Order_Master.Add(neworder);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to save to database: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Entity Model should look something like this:

```
    public class OrderContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Order_Master> Order_Master { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order_Item> Order_Items { get; set; }
        // More entities...
    }

    public class Order_Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Item_Description { get; set; }
        // More properties...
    }

    public class Order_Master
    {
        public Order_Master()
        {
            Order_Item = new List<Order_Item>();
        }

        public ICollection<Order_Item> Order_Item { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Order_Description { get; set; }
        // More properties...
    }
```